# Unreadble errors with Firebase Crash Reporting on ios (Symbol files)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm using firebase crash reporting to get crash on my iphone project.

But the logs that I receive are not readable :

```
Exception name: EXC_BREAKPOINT / EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT

TPC_swift
4295841940 + 284820

TPC_swift
4295841344 + 284224

TPC_swift
4296852240 + 1295120

libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 5304

libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_client_callout + 5240

libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 27520

CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 920908

CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopRun + 912308
9
CoreFoundation
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 35916

GraphicsServices
GSEventRunModal + 49284

UIKit
UIApplicationMain + 516228

TPC_swift
4295904544 + 347424

libdyld.dylib
start + 10420
```

This is an issue with firebase or apple errors ?

In my Build Phases on my project, I have this script :

```
# Replace this path with the path to the key you just downloaded
```

JSON_FILE=/*****/TPC_Swift/TPC_swift/TPC_swift/Project-*****.json

```
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:*********:ios:***************

defaults write com.google.SymbolUpload version -integer 1   # creates file if it does not exist
JSON=$(cat "${JSON_FILE}")
/usr/bin/plutil -replace "app_${GOOGLE_APP_ID//:/_}" -json "${JSON}" "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload.plist"
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym
```

Thank you

**EDIT :**

On firebase, I have :

> Upload symbol file to symbolicate future stack traces for UUID
>   68FD2AAC-F8A7-***********

I think the issue is linked to the symbol files
How to solve this ?

**EDIT 2 :**

I tried "dwarfdump --uuid /path/to/your/build/area/MyApp.app/MyApp"
but I can not retrieved this UUID...

Comment: I got the same issue as well, all the errors are unreadable :(

Comment: @Xero have you found any solution for this problem

Comment: I was having the same issue, take a look on my solution: [ANSWER LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160230/firebase-crashes-unreadable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you find the answer for your question?

Your script seems to be a little different than the one recommended at the [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files) today (Sep 18 2016).

Have you tried this one?

```
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"
```

Comment: This one doesn't work as the compiler complains about "Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"

Answer (score 3):

Facing the same issue, this is what I got from **firebase-support@google.com**:

Thanks for waiting. Can you go over the following items and see it will work:

reset your OAuth credentials, run below command:

```
rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*
```

create new service account and make sure it has editor permission
Revise your script into below format:

```
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
   GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

   # Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
   "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"
```

Please make sure your app id and json file path are correct.
I hope this helps. Let me know if you have other concern.